# Perhaps using 'code' format for displaying UpperCase I as a keyboard key should be standard protocol?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that when showing the uppercase 'I' in keyboard format, unless the letter is enclosed in `` to display it in 'code' format, the result may be easily confused with the lowercase L or a vertical line:

<kbd>I</kbd> vs <kbd>`I`</kbd>

Just in case anyone, like me, is new to this, the ` key is not the apostrophe, but the "[Grave Accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)" found here:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/250/599